# Why does sbt parse Maven's settings.xml

Tags: scala, sbt

By accident I found out today that sbt parses the settings.xml file in Maven's .m2 directory; my settings.xml had an empty line at the beginning and because of this, whenever I started sbt, it emitted a couple of warnings like 'WARNING: Problem parsing /home/me/.m2/settings.xml, The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.'

The problem was easy to fix, I just had to remove the empty line in settings.xml. But I'm really surprised that sbt apparently parses maven's settings.xml. I can't find anything about this in the documentation. I did check my sbt script, my sbt settings and even my .bashrc but there is nothing there that would cause this behaviour.

Has anybody seen this before and if so, do you know why sbt parses maven's settings.xml file every time?

Comment: because the poor `SBT` does not have its own package repository scheme like `maven` has with `m2`. And in most of the sbt project you will be using the same `m2` repository that maven does.

Comment: It's possible that it's _[Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy)_ that is parsing this file. _SBT_ employs _Ivy_ to manage artifacts, and it would make sense for it to re-use artifacts downloaded by _Maven_.